# Git: Automatically configure remotes when cloning

Tags: git, github

I have a repository I with two different remotes: `origin` and `upstream`. However every time I clone the repository I have to manually configure the `upstream` by:

`git remote add upstream <url>`

Is there a way to configure a git repository such that its already configured with `upstream` upon cloning ?

Comment: I don't think so - you only clone from one repository, and there's no way git knows by itself where the other repository is. You could write an git alias to do that, but question is: why do you clone your repository so often, that it becomes an issue?

Comment: Upstream is the main remote while origin can be fork.

Comment: @Kleskowy Its not that I clone it so often. But I moved my repo today to another server and realized of this. I asked just for the sake of learning.

Comment: Take a look at git hooks.

Comment: You can add script or make target or some way to do that in yuor repo. Execute that after cloning.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create an executable hook `post-checkout` in `/foo/hooks/`.

A sample:

```
#!/bin/bash    
git remote add upstream <url>
```

When you are going to clone a repository and you want the `upstream` to be automatically configured, add an option to specify the hook path:

```
git -c core.hookspath=/foo/hooks/ clone <url>
```

So that `post-checkout` under `/foo/hooks/` will be invoked by the checkout in `git clone` as if the hook is under the newly cloned repository.

For easier use, you can make an alias, for example `ch` standing for `clone with hooks`:

```
git config --global alias.ch "-c core.hookspath=/foo/hooks/ clone"
```

Then `git ch <url>` works.

Comment: Thanks, thats what I was looking for!

Comment: What if the repo for which I have to run the hook is a submodule of the repo i am cloning? will that work?

`git -c core.hookspath=/foo/hooks clone --recursive <url>`

Comment: @edgarstack Sorry, I haven't tried. I guess it will work, but the main repo will also have a redundant remote.

Answer (score -1):

```
git remote -a
```

It will show both the remote and upstream.

We use upstream mainly when creating a `fork` from the main repository and whenever we update, we update our remote repository. Letting know the owner of the repository to create a pull request from updated `fork(origin)`.

Comment: I know and that is my case, I forked a repository and I just wanted all my copies to have the same upstream automatically configured.

Comment: It is not possible because there are two remotes synced so you have to mention. Also If you are not the owner you cannot push your commit to upstream directly.

Comment: Also when you create a fork from the repo. You fork is sync with upstream and then you clone a fork which will be origin. Now you push your changes to fork and then create a pull request with upstream that's how git works